# How to update the targetSdkVersion to the Tensorflow Pose Estimation Android App?

Tags: android, tensorflow

I recently started playing around with the Tensorflow Pose Estimation Android Demo App:

https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/pose_estimation/android

but in order to put something on the app store you have to update the targetSdkVersion to a value over 30. When I did this you end up getting errors. This is my first time working on any android app so I'm in a bit over my head here so any help would be appreciated!

Error:

```
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest FAILED
***FILE Name Hidden *** 
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyFloatingActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.


See https://developer.android.com/r/studio-ui/build/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
 Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

Here is the gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.tensorflow.lite.examples.poseestimation"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    namespace 'org.tensorflow.lite.examples.poseestimation'
}

// Download tflite model
apply from:"download.gradle"

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.3"
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.5'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.5.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:2.5.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.3.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.1.3"
}
```

I attempted to look at my Merge Manifest and there are two warnings but I have no idea what to do with these:

```
 Merge Warnings 

Warning: Namespace 'org.tensorflow.lite' used in: AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml. tensorflow-lite:2.7.0 manifest 

Warning: Namespace 'org.tensorflow.lite.support' used in: AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml. tensorflow-lite-support:0.3.0 manifest
```